# полу прозрачные линии на фоне текста

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

полу прозрачные линии  на фоне текста,кстати это шаблон для Django.

HTML

```html
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

CSS

```css
li a {
    color: green;
}

*{
    background: #141121 url("images/background.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    border:none;
}
```

сама проблема
[image]

при масштабе 50%[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи селектора `*` Вы устанавливаете фон для всех элементов. 
Для `li a` используйте `background-color: transparent;`

Причём, если Вы распределите, и установите картинку фона для `body` это сработает.

Если всё-равно хотите использовать селектор `*`, то в `li a` используйте для `background-color: transparent;` параметр `!important`